# Creating a Parse-Server compatible DB

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm migrating off of Parse to self hosted Parse server. In my staging environment, I need to initialize MongoDB so that it has all the collections of my production environment, but no data. Is there a way to do this *without* the data? I've attempted to clone my Parse DB and export the cloned DB's collections, but this has no effect on the collections visible to me through Parse Dashboard. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your data, then use the parse dashboard and delete all the rows.

The database migration tool can be found in the Dashboard under App Settings → General → Migrate to external database.

https://www.parse.com/migration

Comment: I've already migrated my Production database and don't have the option to do it again.

Comment: You should be able to migrate multiple times, you just need to point to the new database. Also, if you don't want the data from the migrate parse dynamically creates the collections in mongo from your app or cloud code when you .save any object. So as long as your mongoDB is set up, you can hook it up to your app and just plug n play.

Comment: @tanz Migrating the whole DB just to have the structure on testing environment is crazy. DB could be 100's go gigs...Any other solution?